How can we automate retrieve or update Color of Einstein Bot Button on Embedded Service Deployment?
We have a requirement to update the Einstein Bot Button color from its current default almost black color value to blue but we struggle to migrate this manual change from one environment to another one.
We have found a line
"TextColor" : "#1a1b1e",

in digitalExperiences/site/ESW/sfdc_cms__brandingSet/Embedded_Service_for_Web_LWR/content.json but even if we change it and try to deploy, nothing changes.
Also we can see in staticResources/SNA_ESW/maintenance.html
--dxp-g-root-contrast:#1a1b1e;

but if we change it and deploy it, also nothing changes.
We have also seen this inside staticResources/SNA_ESW/assets/styles/bootstrap.min.css
as .embeddedMessagingConversationButtonbackground:var(--eswHeaderColor,#1A1B1E)}
which seems to be actual style class used on actual page and actual property, however, if we change it and deploy it, nothing is changed on the Embedded Service Deployment branding.
How can we automate retrieve or update Color of Einstein Bot Button on Embedded Service Deployment?
Is this even possible?

There are two ways.

It is possible to retrieve and deploy as metadata using EmbeddedServiceConfig and BrandindSet metadata. EmbeddedServiceConfig has a reference to branding set


    false
    EmbeddedServiceConfig_BrandingSet_RandomNumber


BrandingSet metadata contains headerColor brandingSetProperty
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BrandingSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <brandingSetProperty>
        <propertyName>headerTextColor</propertyName>
        <propertyValue>#FFFFFF</propertyValue>
    </brandingSetProperty>
    <brandingSetProperty>
        <propertyName>headerColor</propertyName>
        <propertyValue>#FF8775</propertyValue>
    </brandingSetProperty>

which can be used to determine (retrieve) or change and deploy the Einstein Bot Button color.

Also, these are duplicated as Data records. So if we need to update them, we can query them and update

First, get the BrandingSet Id by executing this script
bsId=$(sf data query -q "Select BrandingId  FROM EmbeddedServiceConfig WHERE DeveloperName = 'CUSAESC'" -t  --json  | jq '.result.records[0].BrandingId' -r)

Then we may query the BrandingSetProperty records by executing the following query
sf data query -q "SELECT Id, PropertyName, PropertyValue FROM BrandingSetProperty WHERE PropertyName = 'headerColor' AND BrandingSetId = '$bsId'" --json > headerColor.json

hcbspId=$(cat headerColor.json | jq '.result.records[0].Id' -r)

cat headerColor.json | jq '.result.records[0].PropertyValue' -r

If we need to update the header color, we can just execute
desiredValue=#C0C0C0
sf data update -s BrandingSetProperty -i $hcbspId -v PropertyValue=$desiredValue

Update: SF Created a new knowledge article about this https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=002774306&type=1
